# Purpose of [Char[]] in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

What is the basic purpose of [char[]] in PowerShell. Is it parsing to char array  ? 
For example :

```
$random = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 5;
$names="America","Iran","Poland","Cat","PowerShell";
$targetWord = $names[$random];
[Char[]]$wordProgress =  "_" * $targetWord.Length
```

Comment: Is the "write a hangman game" a common project for PowerShell courses? Which level schooling is this project from?  I am only curious, I have nothing against this question if it is related to home work. I know I've seen at least two other "PowerShell hangman" questions on SO.

Comment: ^ yeah it is a hangman game in powerShell. It's from SE.

Comment: To answer what you really asked here:  the purpose of `[char[]]` is to actually cast a value to a char-array, just like you could case to almost any other .Net type. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell by default does type casting on the fly, as operations call them.

```
$MyAnswer = 4 + 4
Write-Host $MyAnswer
```

Will see the operation 4+4 and store them as an integer value of 8. In the above script it will write the integer 8.

PowerShell is also flexible for strict typecasting where you can explicitly use a datatype

```
$MyAnswer = [string]4 + 4
Write-Host $MyAnswer
```

and

```
$MyAnswer = "4" + "4"
Write-Host $MyAnswer
```

Both of these will see the two 4's as a string, and write out "44"

As for what the script above is doing, it is creating a character array of "_ " characters for each letter (char) in the $targetWord variable.

If you run it from the console, and do

write-host $targetWord
   write-host $wordProgress

You get (in my case)

```
 America
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

The [char[]] is simply an explicit declaration of a character array to over ride any odd default PowerShell behavior.

Comment: "_" * $targetWord.Length what is this

Comment: Its a multiplication operation, it does character "_" times the length of the word in the $targetWord variable.

Comment: The information that [string]$MyAnswer=4+4 will output 4+4 is incorrect. Because you are using [string] on the left side, first the calculation will be carried out and the result (8) will be stored in the variable of string type.

Comment: @AdilH YOU ARE RIGHT, UPDATED.